# my object doesn't follow a path

Tags: animation

I am trying to move the model along the path(a bit hard to see but a direct line is on along Y-axis )

I set "following path" , selected the target and pressed "animation path" however, only  the blue line from object follows the path but the object itself.
How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: Pls provide blend file

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/c1f0601807cd431895ce99b6156c10fa   alright here is the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Controller is disabled (eye icon)

[image]

Comment: ohh because at first my object disappeared when I put follow path, and I pressed the eye mark and it made the object appear again so I thought it is about hide/unhide. But I tried it again and it works properly ! thank you